# Making an image a background with CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am trying to make this section on my website use an image instead of a color. Currently it is using a white color, but I want an image that I have in the folder.

Here is the CSS:

```
.page {
  width: 100%;
}
.section {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 100px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.padding-top-off {
  padding-top: 0;
}
.padding-bottom-off {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.padding-off {
  padding: 0;
}
.padding-top-half-off {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.border {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ececec;
}
```

Comment: type background:url('to your image url');

Comment: You haven't actually tried anything, based on the code you've posted.

Comment: Do some [reading on the background property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

Comment: [**google search**](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=image%20as%20background%20css) ...at least make an effort

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
background-color: #fff;
```

to

```
background:url('insert image link/location here')
```

Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp) link it might as well help you to learn the basics of CSS.

Keep in mind that searching  on Google would provide you a quicker answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
background:url('your image link/location');
```

For example:

```
background:url('https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-4jDD67VW8zI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABE/Caii4FguqIo/photo.jpg?sz=128');
```